# How to connect SQL Server 2012 Database created with SSMS to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am using SQL Server Management Studio for the first time. I have created a project and I created one database in it. How can I connect that database to Visual Studio 2013.
If I go to Tools -> Connect to Database
I get this 
[image]

Then after selecting Microsoft SQL Server I browse to my database and I am getting this
[image]
What should I do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already added the database to your Sql Server you can't select `Attach a Database file` and then `Browse` for the same MDF file already added to Sql Server. Instead you choose `Select or enter a database name` and select the logical database name from the list proposed.